# Cannot find instance of an object

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

The problem I am facing at the moment is that right now I have warnings:
[image]

which are created by this code snippet:
[image]

But if I correct the code by changing line 24 to:
[image]

The result is an error saying that in line 24 the insance is not declared, in the picture is visible that I added the script to my GameObject, but it has no variables filled in.
[image]

Been dealing with this for 2 days now, really need your help. Thank you!

Comment: Its `AddComponent<...>() and GetComponent<...>()` - not `AddComponent.<...>() and GetComponent.<...>()`

Comment: removed the dots, but different errors show up

Comment: To clarify, are "CatFiltered110" and "CatFiltered1.10" referring to two different GameObjects?

Comment: No, that is the same object. "CatFiltered1.10" is the objects name inside the scene and CatFiletered110 is a reference name to the same object in the script

Comment: Hm, I think there may be some confusion on what `GameObject.Find()` is for, then. It's only for grabbing objects within the scene, not variables on scripts as well - can you try using `CatFiltered110.AddComponent<enablePrintedPage>();` instead of `GameObject.Find("CatFiltered110").AddComponent<enablePrintedPage>();`?

Comment: I see the error gone from the console as to not being able to find, but for me it works only if there is the dot e.g. .<Renderer>(); , without it I get synthax errors

Comment: Right now the script keeps adding even though I put the CatFiltered110.AddComponent<enablePrintedPage>(); in function Start()

Comment: Can you provide the updated code with the new problems you're facing? It can be hard to pinpoint the problem based on description alone.

Comment: Just to check, i notice you changed your gameobject names. You updated them in you hierarchy as well?

Comment: @Desu, yes I did update them in the scene hierarchy aswell

Comment: @Royal the gameobjects are active in the hierarchy? If not actived them, otherwise GameObject.Find(...) ain't working

Comment: @Desu they are active.

Answer (score 1):

Change all your code with GetCompenent and AddComponent into:

```
rendCat110 = CatFiltered110.GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

the `.` you have after GetComponent will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
(dots in wrong position)

```
#pragma strict
var CatClickFinished : CatClickFinished;
var passToDisable;
var rendCat110 : Renderer;
var rendCat210 : Renderer;
var enablePrintedPage : enablePrintedPage;
var enableCats;
var increment : int = 0;
var CatFiltered110 : GameObject;
var CatFiltered210 : GameObject;

var enabledCat110210 : boolean = false;

function Start () {
    CatFiltered110 = GameObject.Find("CatFiltered1.10");
    rendCat110 = CatFiltered110.GetComponent<Renderer>();

    CatFiltered210 = GameObject.Find("CatFiltered2.10");
    rendCat210 = CatFiltered210.GetComponent<Renderer>();



}

function Update () {

    GameObject.Find("CatFiltered110").AddComponent<enablePrintedPage>();
    enableCats = enablePrintedPage.enableCats;

    GameObject.Find("CatFiltered110").AddComponent<CatClickFinished>();
    passToDisable = CatClickFinished.passToDisable;

    SymbolsEnabled();
    DisableSprite();
}

function OnMouseOver(){
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
        rendCat110.enabled = true;
        rendCat210.enabled = true;
        enabledCat110210 = true;
    }
}

    function SymbolsEnabled(){
        if(enableCats && increment == 0){
            var cat : BoxCollider = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>(); //enabled box colliders on cat symbols
            increment = 1;
        }
    }

    function DisableSprite(){
        if(passToDisable){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```